# Laravel Illuminate/Support/Facade/DB not found

Tags: php, laravel, configuration

I recently cloned my project from github to my local machine for development. I am using the Laravel framework and have been having issues getting my web service working because it cannot find Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
My code looks like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
...(filler code)...
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('....'))
```

I end up getting this as an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/plotly_dawgs/service_data.php:50
```

If anyone knows why this might be please let me know.
I've tried reupdating composer dependencies and checked alias => [] in app.php

Comment: Why are you calling DB facade from the view? Also, view name should be `.blade.php`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin That was my fault, moved it out in the main directory it's not suppose to be there.  Still getting the same error when called though.